# Devise Invitable showing accepted invites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

I'm trying to show who a user invited that has accepted the invitation.

Right now, this is what I have:

```
@invites = User.where(invited_by_id: @user.id)
```

But this also lists blank users that still have not accepted the invite, how do I show only the users that accepted the invitations by a given user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like to see actual `where` code so i usually do it like this:

```
@invites = User.where.not(invitation_accepted_at: nil).where(invited_by_id: @user.id)
```

Note this uses the rails 4 syntax `where.not`

Comment: I like the new syntax, but I do not like to concat several where clauses (.where(..).where(...)) to get (... AND...). Like in SQL I do like only having a where clause.

Comment: I personally don't mind them, but one way around it is to just create class methods (`self.invitation_not_accepted`)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the field `invitation_accepted_at` will be `nil` until the invitation is accepted. So this would be the query (compatible with Rails 3 as well):

```
@invites = User.where("invited_by_id = ? AND invitation_accepted_at IS NOT ?", @user.id, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code above will run in a weird way. There is some helpers ***(invitation_not_accepted & invitation_accepted)*** in the Devise_invitable docs. With a bit of custom :

Directly in the View :

```
<%= Member.invitation_not_accepted.where(invited_by_id: current_member.id).count %>

<%= Member.invitation_accepted.where(invited_by_id: current_member.id).count %>
```